# What could be causing lights to be flickering and multiple breakers tripping and won't reset?

Tags: electrical

I was outside yesterday when my wife called to me saying the lights in the kitchen were flickering. Next thing I know the power to the TV went out so I went downstairs to the breaker box to find that 5 of the breakers had tripped. When I went to reset them only 2 would reset. I called my electrician who wasn't sure but had some ideas which I wasn't quite fallowing.. And he swapped out one of the less needed breakers that worked for one that was broken until he could get some new ones seeing it is a holiday weekend. He left, I went to do errands I when I returned I found six more breakers are tripped And broken.... And as I write this the lights in the kitchen are flickering every few minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: I would, among others, check that all wires that go into breaker panel are firmly attached

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd flip the master breaker and shut everything down **until** you know what is going on.

Something is seriously wrong with your wiring system, possibly the breaker panel itself has developed a really bad internal fault with how the breakers attach to the bus bars.

We just lost a house across the street due to a wiring fire as of 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah -- this is a classic symptom of busbar trouble.  I don't care if it's a holiday weekend, either -- that panel's a ticking time bomb.